# Why is text within inner tag ignored, how to fix it?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<p>The latest media Tweets from Yohir Akerman (@yohirakerman). My bio changes all the time. /// akermancolumnista<strong>@gmail.com</strong>. Airplane</p>
```

I try to extract the entire text as follows:

```
    body = response.xpath('//*[@id="b_results"]/p/text()").getall()
    print(body)
```

The out put I get is:

```
['The latest media Tweets from Yohir Akerman (@yohirakerman). My bio changes '
 'all the time. /// akermancolumnista',
 '. Airplane']
```

The entire text within `<strong>` tag is ignore , how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `text()` . Inside

```
body = response.xpath('//*[@id="b_results"]/p").getall()
    print(body)
```

Then join body and clean body of all tags.